# How does static keyword work internally?

Tags: objective-c, c

How does the `static` keyword works internally? Considering the base definition `static variable is initialized only once`, how does the `run-time` or `compile` time interprets it in terms of execution flow? Consider code snippet:

```
void function()
   {
      static int count=0;
      count++;
   }
main()
    {
       for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
          function();
    }
```

The line  `static int count=0;` is executed only once and that to in iteration `i=0` is the best explanation I can come up with. Is it correct or does it work some other way?

And where in memory is a static variable stored `stack` or `heap`?

Also is there something called `static object` in `Objective-C`? If there is how is it different from normal object?

Comment: `static` has *so* many different meanings, you really have to give a more complete code example.

Comment: Also, what does it mean that "the compiler skips it after the first encounter"? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorial in web which you can refer, simply google - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx

Comment: While the question might not be well formulated, I don't think it grants for such a downvote spree... Upvoting to compensate a little. Jesly, as other comments mention, you should edit the question and make it a bit more precise. You might or might not be aware of the multiple meanings of `static` in the three languages (and in some cases the meaning might even differ --I don't know Obj-C, so cannot comment there). State what usage of `static`, and what language you are really interested in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last question suggests you're asking about the case where `static` is used in a local variable declaration.

> How does the static keyword work internally?

That's implementation-specific.

> Does this have anything to do with the memory being allocated?

Yes, locals declared with `static` reside in static storage.

> does the compiler/runtime just skip it after the first encounter?

It's the runtime that *executes the initialization* only once. `static` locals are value-initialized, unless otherwise noted.

Answer (score 2):

It means something to the compiler and to the way memory is allocated depending on where it is.  Inside a function variables are allocated on the stack and persist for the life of the function and the value is not retained between calls.  With a `static` declaration the variable is allocated where globals are allocated (usually .bss) and the value persists between function calls but the scope of the variable is only to that function.

When `static` is used for global declarations outside of a function then the variable only has scope in that module.  That is if you declare a static variable in module1.cpp then module2.cpp cannot access it with extern.